Jwt -Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"
"Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"" in the token verification process with the connection between the frontend and microservisim
I'm getting error
Frontend Program.cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<AuthServiceClient>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/"); // AuthService URL'si
});
// JWT Authentication ve Authorization ayarlarını ekleyin
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,`your text`
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        };

        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                // JWT token'ı cookie'den alır
                context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["AuthToken"];
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnTokenValidated = context =>
            {
                // Başarılı token doğrulaması sonrası işlemler
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                // Token doğrulama hatası sonrası işlemler
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

Frontend appsetting.json
  "Jwt": {
    "Key": "SuperSecretKey@345",
    "Issuer": "AuthService",
    "Audience": "EducationPlatformUsers",
    "ExpiresInMinutes": 60
  },

Auth Microservice Program.cs
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = jwtSettings["Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = jwtSettings["Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings["Key"]))
    };
});

Auth Microservice Appsetting.json
"Jwt": {
   "Key": "SuperSecretKey@345",
   "Issuer": "AuthService",
   "Audience": "EducationPlatformUsers",
   "ExpiresInMinutes": 60
 },

JWT settings are correct, but I could not verify the token and I could not authenticate or authorize the login process.

Hi, I could only see the jwt validation mechainsm configuration but I can't see how you generate the access token and how to call the API. Could you please take a look at this sample and check whether you missed any steps?
